# My Splash Screen in Ubuntu isn't centered since I updated to 21.04

Tags: boot, plymouth

Today I decided to update from Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04, and the first thing I noticed while shutting down was that my splash screen was shifted to the right-bottom, as you can see in the picture below.
I already looked at the `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script` file, and it looks alright. The section where it calculates the position of the Picture also looks fine to me.

```
logo.image = Image (logo_filename);
logo.sprite = Sprite ();
logo.sprite.SetImage (logo.image);
logo.width = logo.image.GetWidth ();
logo.height = logo.image.GetHeight ();
logo.x = Window.GetX () + Window.GetWidth () / 2 - logo.width  / 2;
logo.y = Window.GetY () + Window.GetHeight () / 2 - logo.height;
logo.z = 1000;
logo.sprite.SetX (logo.x);
logo.sprite.SetY (logo.y);
logo.sprite.SetZ (logo.z);
logo.sprite.SetOpacity (1);
```

My modifications to the splash screen (black background and white/black dots) also work without any problems.

```
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);     # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.01, 0.01, 0.01);  # an equally nice colour on the bottom
```

(I changed the `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/progress-dot-on.png` file to be completely transparent.)

Please Help me, thanks.

[image: Picture of the Splash Screen]

Comment: I have the same issue after updating from Kubuntu 20.10 to 21.04. It seems like a bug, have you filed a bug report yet?

Comment: @Derkades no I haven't. I didn't think about it anymore since I reinstalled ubuntu (for another reason) a few weeks later